# Let $P(x)=x^5+x^2+1$ and the equation has roots $x_1,x_2,..x_5$.

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $P(x)=x^5+x^2+1$ and the equation has roots $x_1,x_2,..x_5$.
>   If $g(x)=x^2-2$, then find the value of $g(x_1)g(x_2)....g(x_5)$

I have no idea on how to begin. Clearly, they can’t all be multiples, as it would take an eternity.

What I noticed was that the sum of roots is zero, and the product is 1, but I don’t think that’s very useful.

Comment: Why the title and the body of the question are different???

Comment: @KiênP.S. He split the statement between the title and the question body. I took the liberty of writing the complete statement in the question body.

Comment: @Atticus Oh OK. I understand

Comment: What you want to do is a websearch for *resultant*. Ignore any links that explain the meaning of the word in physics – you want the links that talk about *algebra*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write

$$P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^5(x-x_i)=(-1)^5\cdot\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i-x)=-\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i-x)$$

so

$$-P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i-x)$$

From this, setting $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$, we get that:

$$-P(\sqrt{2})=\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i-\sqrt{2})$$

and

$$-P(-\sqrt{2})=\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i+\sqrt{2})$$

Now

$$g(x_1)=(x_1-\sqrt{2})(x_1+\sqrt{2})$$

so

$$g(x_1)g(x_2)g(x_3)g(x_4)g(x_5)=\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i-\sqrt{2})\prod_{i=1}^5(x_i+\sqrt{2})=$$
$$[-P(\sqrt{2})]\cdot [-P(-\sqrt{2}]=P(\sqrt{2})P(-\sqrt{2})$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Could you clarify why in the last line you wrote $P(-\sqrt 2)P(\sqrt 2)$?

Comment: @Aditya, I added some detail. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not. What does the negative sign have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Aditya, I flip the order of $x$ and $x_i$: $(x-x_i)=-(x_i-x)$. Since there are $5$ factors, we get in front a factor of $(-1)^5=-1$. That's were the negative sign comes from.

Comment: Okay, but how does $\prod_{i=1}^5 (x_i-\sqrt 2)$ translate into $P(\sqrt 2)$? What exactly is the connection between them ?

Comment: @Aditya $\prod_{i=1}^5 (x_i-\sqrt 2)$ translates into $-P(\sqrt{2})$ (as per the demonstration in the first line). I edited again. Hopefully, it's clearer now. If not, I'm here for further questions.

Comment: I am not really that concerned about the signs than I am for how the function P inserted in there in the first place.

Comment: @Aditya, so you are not sure about $P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^5(x-x_i)$? Or can you pinpoint the exact step that is unclear?

Comment: Yes exactly, that’s where I am having a problem

Comment: @Aditya, this is pretty important. If we have a polynomial $P(x)=a_0x^n+...+a_{n-1}x+a_1$ with the roots $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$, then we have: $$P(x)=a_{0}(x-r_{1})\cdots (x-r_{n})$$

In our case, the leading coefficient $a_0$ is $1$.

If the coefficients of P are real or complex numbers, the fundamental theorem of algebra asserts that P has a real or complex root. Using the factor theorem recursively, it results that:

$$P(x)=a_{0}(x-r_{1})\cdots (x-r_{n})$$

Comment: @Aditya, you can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Polynomials

Comment: I thought so too, but then why have you left the $x_i$ term untouched, which is supposed to be the root of the equation? Shouldn’t the roots of be of the form $(x-x_i)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104746/discussion-between-atticus-and-aditya).

Comment: Also your previous version, ie. the one before the new edit actually explained it very well until the last step. The new one is a bit confusing .